# Python virtualenv: Why is pip still looking in a non-$path path?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I've been keeping all my python2.7 installs in my `~/.local/` directory that way I don't have to `sudo` every time I want to do a `pip install`. I also have `$HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` on my `$PYTHONPATH`.  This has worked well for years but now I find myself needing to run `python3` programs more frequently.  After much research it seems like `virtualenv` is the most recommended way to deal with `python` 2 and 3 on the same system.  But I am running into troubles.  I can spin up a `python3` virtual environment but when I try to install new libs with `pip`, my old global path (i.e. `~/.local/`) is still being searched by `pip`, which makes sense.  However, this is even the case if I remove my `~/.local/bin/` directory from my `$PATH` and unset my `$PYTHONPATH`.
Here is are the steps I took:
First check the preliminaries before activating `virtualenv`. (I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 btw)

```
maddoxw@firefly:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:/home/maddoxw/.node_modules_global/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/maddoxw/bin:/home/maddoxw/scripts
maddoxw@firefly:~$ echo $PYTHONPATH

maddoxw@firefly:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
maddoxw@firefly:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
maddoxw@firefly:~$ which pip
```

Since I removed my `~/.local/bin` directory from my path, then I can be certain `pip` will not be found.  Also, `$PYTHONPATH` is still empty.  Now I create my `virtualenv`:

```
maddoxw@firefly:~$ mkdir test && cd test/
mkdir: created directory 'test'
maddoxw@firefly:~/test$ python3 -m venv .env
maddoxw@firefly:~/test$ source .env/bin/activate
(.env) maddoxw@firefly:~/test$ echo $PATH
/home/maddoxw/test/.env/bin:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:/home/maddoxw/.node_modules_global/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/maddoxw/bin:/home/maddoxw/scripts
(.env) maddoxw@firefly:~/test$ echo $PYTHONPATH

(.env) maddoxw@firefly:~/test$ which python
/home/maddoxw/test/.env/bin/python
(.env) maddoxw@firefly:~/test$ python --version
Python 3.5.2
(.env) maddoxw@firefly:~/test$ which pip
/home/maddoxw/test/.env/bin/pip
```

Good. My `~/.local/` is still NOT on my `$PATH`, `$PYTHONPATH` is still empty, `python` points to the correct path and version, and `pip` is pointing to the correct location.  Now lets try to `pip install` a fresh lib.

```
(.env) maddoxw@firefly:~/test$ pip install Cython
Requirement already satisfied: Cython in /home/maddoxw/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Why is `pip` still looking in a non-`$PATH` path?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's doing that but if all else fails you can run the desired pip directly with `<path_to_env>/bin/pip install cython`

Answer (score 0):

First, install **pip3** to use with python3. You can install it with the following command and then use **pip3** to install your packages.

**sudo apt-get install python3-pip**

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]

When I initially set up my `python2.7` environment way back when, I created for myself a handy little function wrapper around `pip` so that I wouldn't have to type out the `--user` every time I wanted to `pip install`

```
pip() {
  if [ "$1" = "install" -o "$1" = "bundle" ]; then
    cmd="$1"
    shift
    $HOME/.local/bin/pip $cmd --user $@
  else
    $HOME/.local/bin/pip $@
  fi
}
```

I put this function in `~/.bash.d/bash_functions`
and in my ~/.bashrc i added the line,

```
[ -f ~/.bash.d/bash_functions ] && source ~/.bash.d/bash_functions
```

So, although I removed `$HOME/.local/` from my path.  This wrapper function was still being called everytime I fired up a new terminal.  Weather or not I was or was not in a virtualenv was irrelevant.

Solution?

Commented out (or delete completely) the function wrapper fixed it.